# Adding to the end of a smarty variable

Tags: php, smarty

One quick question. What would be the easiest way of adding to a smarty variable ?.

My variable is `{$menu.url}` for an example. That one is echoing out

```
http://www.domain.com/page/pagename
```

But i wan't to add a "/" at the end of the variable so it's echoing out

```
http://www.domain.com/page/pagename/
```

with a forward slash at the end.

Any ideas on how to do this within the variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can append a string to php variable and then assign it to smarty variable

E.g

```
     $menu_url='http://www.domain.com/page/pagename/';
     $smarty->assign('url',$menu_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the view ,for a variable x this is how you concatenate it's value with a `/` :

```
{assign var=x value="$x/"}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [cat](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.cat.tpl):

if you just want to output it:
{$menu.url|cat:'/'}

if you want to add it to the variable:
{$menu.url=$menu.url|cat:'/'}